# События открытия и закрытия bootstrap3-collapse в Yii2 Collapse виджете

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2, bootstrap

Имеется проект на Yii2 в котором есть интерфейс с вложенными друг в друга коллапсами. Ниже привожу код:
`index.php`:

```
<?= Collapse::widget([
    'items' => [
        [
            'label' => 'Collapse1',
            'content' => $this->render('1'),
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Collapse2',
            'content' => $this->render('2'),
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Collapse3',
            'content' => $this->render('3'),
        ],
    ]
]); ?>
```

`1.php`:

```
<?= Collapse::widget([
    'items' => [
        [
            'label' => 'Collapse1',
            'content' => $this->render('1_1'),
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Collapse2',
            'content' => $this->render('1_2'),
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Collapse3',
            'content' => $this->render('1_3'),
        ],
    ]
]); ?>
```

И так далеее...
Выглядит это следующим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Для реализации некоторого функционала мне требуется отслеживать открытие-закрытие коллапсов на странице интерфейса. Для этого я решил использовать [события](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse-events) предоставленные разработчиками bootstrap3: `shown.bs.collapse` и `hidden.bs.collapse`.
Итак, для тестирования я набросал следующий скрипт:

```
var collapse = $('.panel-collapse .collapse');

collapse.on('shown.bs.collapse', function ()
{
    var active = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log('Showing collapse with ' + active +  ' id');
});

collapse.on('hidden.bs.collapse', function ()
{
    var active = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log('Hidden collapse with ' + active +  ' id');
});
```

Соответственно, я ожидаю увидеть следующее: при первоначальной загрузке сраницы все коллапсы закрыты. Далее, если я открываю или закрываю коллапс в консоль выводится соответсвующее сообщение.

**Проблемы с которыми я столкнулся:**

1. При первоначальной загрузке страницы, когда все коллапсы еще закрыты, у меня срабатывает событие `shown.bs.collapse` и в консоль выводится сообщение: `Showing collapse with #w1-collapse3 id` говорящее о том, что отрисовался коллапс #2.
2. Когда я открываю самый внешний коллапс (на рисунке #1) - я не получаю уведомление в консоль, следовательно событие `shown.bs.collapse` не срабатывает.
3. Когда я открываю внутренний коллапс (на рисунке #3) срабатывает событие `shown.bs.collapse` и в консоль выводится два сообщения говорящих  о том, что отрисовался коллапсы #2 и #3, хотя коллапс #2 и так уже был отрисован.

   `Showing collapse with #w0-collapse1 id Showing collapse with #w1-collapse3 id`

**Собственно вопрос, почему так происходит, и как это вылечить**?

Comment: В js события всплывают и срабатывают не только на элементе на котором вызваны, но и на родителях. Т.е если повесить обработчик на клик на див, но кликнуть на кнопку внутри дива, то на диве тоже сработает. Так же и здесь. Если нужно получить элемент на котором непосредственно было вызвано событие, то можно обратиться к event.target (event - аргумент функции обработчика)

Comment: @empy26, cпасибо за подсказку! Я прочитал про `event.target`, это действительно объясняет поведение с  всплытием событий. Я добавил следующую проверку условия `if (this === event.target)` и это позволило решить проблему с лишним отображением событий в консоли. Но я до сих пор не могу понять, почему у меня не срабатывает событие `shown.bs.collapse` в том случае когда я открываю любой из первых внешних коллапсов(*проблема #2 в моем вопросе*)?