# Выполнение действия после срабатывания группы событий

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется интерфейс с многократно вложенными друг в друга коллапсами. Пример можно посмотреть здесь: [События открытия и закрытия bootstrap3-collapse в Yii2 Collapse виджете](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/931002/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-bootstrap3-collapse-%D0%B2-yii2-collapse-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5)

Задача состоит в том, что бы раскрыть определеный коллапс, и проскролить экран к раскрытому коллапсу. Получается, по условию задачи, мне нужно открыть так же и все коллапсы-родители целевого. Я написал следующий код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        //some code...
        openCollapse(elementId);
        var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
        element.scrollIntoView();
    });


    function openCollapse (elementId) {
        var targetCollapse = $('#' + elementId);
        var parents = targetCollapse.parents('.panel-collapse').toArray().reverse();
        parents.push(targetCollapse);

        $.each(parents, function (key, object) {
            $(object).collapse('show');
        });
    }
```

Метод `scrollIntoView()` не срабатывает, как я понимаю по той причине, выполнение функции `collapse('show')` занимает какое то время, и в момент вызова `scrollIntoView()` элемент на странице еще не видим. Более того, для корректного смещения экрана необходимо дождаться когда отрисуются все интерфейсы, и только потом делать скролл.
На данный момент, единственный выход который я вижу, это каким то образом подписаться на событие `shown.bs.collapse` у целевого элемента и всех его родителей, и совершать скролл только тогда когда все эти события произойдут. Но как это сделать? Или я слишком усложняю и существует более простое решение?

**UPD1:**
Хочу уточнить, что данный код должен выполнятся сразу при загрузке страницы. `Id` целевого коллапса берется из `get` параметра.
Я так же попытался решить эту задачу с помощью Deffered объектов, но это тоже не привело к результату:

```
$(function() {
    var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    var anchor = searchParams.get('anchor');
    if (!anchor) {
        throw new TypeError('There is no "anchor" parameter in the URL');
    }
    openCollapse(anchor).done(function () {
        var element =  document.getElementById(anchor);
        element.scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth',
            block: 'start'
        });
        console.log('It worked on main function');
    });
});

function openCollapse (elementId) {
    var promises = [];
    var targetCollapse = $('#' + elementId);
    if (!targetCollapse.hasClass('collapse')) {
        throw new TypeError('error');
    }
    var parents = targetCollapse.parents('.panel-collapse').toArray().reverse();
    parents.push(targetCollapse);

    $.each(parents, function (key, object) {
        var dfd = new $.Deferred();
        $(object).collapse('show');
        $(object).on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
            dfd.resolve();
        });
        promises.push(dfd);
    });

    return $.when.apply($, promises).promise();
}
```

В данном варианте, проблема в том, что все коллапсы раскрываются, но на целевом коллапсе почему-то не срабатывает метод `dfd.resolve()`. Хотя в том случа если я вручню закрою и открою целевой коллапс, то `resolve` срабатывает, и блок кода в `done` основной функции выполняется. Немогу понять почему происходит такое поведение, и что я делаю не так?

Comment: _мне нужно открыть так же и все коллапсы-родители целевого._ Какой-то странный у вас интерфейс. Как вообще юзер может увидеть/нажать целевой коллапс, если его родители закрыты? Или это программное действие?

Comment: @hindmost, конечно программное, юзер должен получтить готовый результат

Comment: Ну и в чем проблема? Вы же сами написали про событие `shown.bs.collapse`, вот и слушайте его. только у родителей не надо слушать. вы последним открываете (`collapse('show')`) целевой элемент - вот у него и слушайте.

Comment: @hindmost, смотрите какая ситуация получается: `collapse('show')` вызывает анимацию раскрытия коллапса, по завершении которой срабатывает событие `shown.bs.collapse`. Я плохо понимаю javascript, но вызывая последовательно в цикле `collapse('show')` на дереве вложенных коллапсов, разве я могу быть уверен, что к после завершения цикла все события `shown.bs.collape` произойдут? По крайней мере я пишу это уже опробовав этот подход - скролл получается некорректным

Comment: _разве я могу быть уверен, что к после завершения цикла все события shown.bs.collape произойдут?_ А зачем вам _**все**_ события? вам нужно только одно - для целевого элемента. Повесьте общий обработчик для всех коллапсов и в нем определяйте целевой элемент через `this` или `event.target`. Сейчас в вашем коде этого нет, нет никаких обработчиков, поэтому он и не работает.

Comment: @hindmost тот вариант что вы предлагаете тоже не работает. Он будет работать только в том случае если в обработчике события поставить таймаут в районе секунды на действие скролла(возможно элементы становтся доступны не сразу, я не очень понимаю этот момент в js). Но это костыль, такой вариант не подходит. https://pastebin.com/MXKY9AX9

Comment: таймаут надо ставить не в обработчике, а при вызове `collapse('show')`. а в обработчике его надо удалять (таймаут). Не совсем понял чем вас этот вариант не устраивает. Походу вам не угодишь)

Comment: @hindmost а вы можете объяснить по какой причине возникает необходимость в таймауте  в данном примере?

Comment: Похоже мы про разные варианты говорили). В общем см. ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Выделяем "глобальную" переменную под целевой элемент, до которого нужно скролить, назовем ее `elemToScroll`.

При вызове `openCollapse` присваиваем `elemToScroll` ссылку на выбранный элемент, причем DOM-элемент, а не jquery-объект, т.к. мы будем вызывать на нем DOM метод `scrollIntoView`. Кстати, у вас в коде ошибка: вы добавляете к `parents` jquery-объект, хотя нужно DOM-элемент.

Вешаем общий обработчик для всех коллапсов на событие `shown.bs.collapse`. В нем нужно убедиться что событие вызвано именно на целевом элементе. для этого сравниваем `elemToScroll` с элементом на к-ом вызвано событие, его можно получить через `this` или `event.target`. Если они совпадают, значит именно тот элемент что нужен. Тогда вызываем метод `scrollIntoView`.

Еще можно поставить таймаут чтобы очищать `elemToScroll` напр-р через 1 сек после вызова `openCollapse`, так, на всякий случай.

Итого, код:

```
var elemToScroll = null;

$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    elemToScroll && this === elemToScroll && elemToScroll.scrollIntoView();
    elemToScroll = null;
});

function openCollapse(elementId) {
    var $el = $('#' + elementId), el = $el[0];
    $el.parents('.collapse')
    .toArray().reverse().concat([el])
    .forEach(el) {
        $(el).collapse('show');
    });
    elemToScroll = el;
    setTimeout(function () {
        elemToScroll = null;
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но `scrollIntoView()` попросту не срабатывает. Хочу уточнить, что этот код выполняется сразу при загрузке страницы. Это выглядит так: достаю из  `get` параметра `id` нужного коллапса, раскрываю его, и делаю скролл. С раскрытием никаких проблем нет, но проблема с прокруткой. Если в вашем или моём коде саму процедуру `scrollIntoView` завернуть в `setTimeout` - прокрутка произойдёт. Исходя из этого я делаю вывод, что скорее всего, в момент попытки этот элемент недоступен. Есть идеи как решить это не прибегая к таймауту?

Comment: @Roman Andreev Попробуйте добавить `console.log` в обработчик, напр-р: `console.log(this.id + ',' + elemToScroll.id)`

Comment: эти `id` совпадают, как и ожидается

Comment: Что, везде совпадают? обработчик должен вызываться на всех коллапсах, и на родителях они не должны совпадать.

Comment: все верно, событие срабатывает несколько раз и на родителях `id` конечно не совпадают, но по условию задачи скролл должен произойти только в том случае если `id` будут совпадать, и такое событие срабатывает. Только скролл не происходит :(

Comment: Ну тогда возможно это какой-то косяк в бутстрапе, это же их кастомное событие. Попробуйте тогда обернуть вызов `scrollIntoView` в `setTimeout(..., 0)`

Comment: На заметку: есть также другой, более нативный способ - отслеживать изменения в `classList` коллапсов через [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). Но это на порядок сложнее реализовать.

Comment: о `setTimeout` я писал еще выше. Конечно, так будет работать, но это костыль, и хотелось бы этого избежать. Про `MutationObserver` незнал, почитаю, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Общее решение для такого типа задач — [промисы](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise).

Если вам нужно дождаться пока все операции(1) закончат выполнение и ТОЛЬКО после этого выполнить другую операцию(2), то необходимо  операции (1) заворачивать в промисы, и передать их в метод Promise.all, передающий управление операции (2) только при «выполнении» всех промисов.

В данном случае вам нужно завернуть события всех родителей и целевого элемента, сложить промисы в массив `eventsPromises` и вызвать Promise.all:

```
Promise.all.apply(Promise, eventsPromises).then(function() {
    elem.scrollIntoView()
});
```

Скроллинг выполнится только после `resolve` всех объектов `Promise`.

Так-же это можно сделать через [jQuery.Deffered](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/) с помощью метода $.when.

Ньюанс решения:

Вам нужно как-то блокировать взаимодействие с collapsible-элементами до тех пор пока не закончится предыдущая анимация, например через переменную `isAnimated`, иначе, если пользователь будет быстро кликать, то возникнет очередь промисов и `scrollIntoView` будет работать неправильно.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Я пытался решить эту задачу с помощью промисов, но такой вариант тоже не прокатил. Вот полный код решения https://pastebin.com/VVu0Y7N5
Проблема в том, что целевой коллапс(я его добавляю в конец массива `parents`)  раскрывается, но объект созданный  deffered object почему то не ресолвится :(
Хотя если после загрузки старницы закрыть и открыть коллапс вручную, то `resolve` происходит, и блок кода `done` в основной функции выполняется. Можете подсказать что я делаю не так?

Comment: Хм, судя по коду все должно работать. debugger; - ом проверяли метод each и подписку на событие при загрузке страницы?